# AS3, Adding an event listener to a constructor class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

this is probably really simple I cannot for the life of me work out why this is not working. I am trying to create an object (only for testing) and assign event listeners within the constructor. In my head it should work but I am sure I must be missing something:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 

public class Box extends MovieClip {

    public function Box() {
        // constructor code
        var mySound:Sound = new Bark();
        trace("Box created");
        height=800;
        width=300;
        x=100;
        y=100;
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overThis);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickToPlay);
    }

    public function overThis(m:MouseEvent){
        trace("SADF");          
    }

    function clickToPlay(m:MouseEvent){
        mySound.play();
    }

}}
```

By doing this i wanted the "box" to be self sufficient in regards to managing its own events. (Please ignore stuff like play(), that all works when I run within the MAINDOC.as directly.

This is the main doc:

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;

public class MainDoc extends MovieClip
{
    public function MainDoc()
    {
        // constructor code
        init();

        function init()
        {
            createBox(300,300);
        }

        function createBox(newX,newY)
        {
            var box = new Box();
            box.x = newX;
            box.y = newY;
            addChild(box);
        }

    }
}}
```

When I test it creates the box (which i have drawn) but does not run any events?

Hope you guys can help

Ray

Answer (score 2):

You have to add some graphics to your box so your MouseEvents can work:

```
public function Box() 
{
    // constructor code
    var mySound:Sound = new Bark();
    trace("Box created");

    // begin the filling of some graphics, you can change color/alpha as you want
    this.graphics.beginFill( 0x000000, 1 );
    // make a rectangle 300x800
    this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,300,800);
    // stop filling
    this.graphics.endFill();


    // you don't need it anymore
    //height=800;
    // you don't need it anymore
    //width=300;

    // place your clip where you want but you do that in the Main class so no need there
    //x=100;
    //y=100;

    // now you have graphics attached to your MovieClip the MouseEvent must work
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overThis);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickToPlay);
}
```

Hope that will help you :)

Comment: Thanks Binou, I had stored the graphics in the Library and created a class that way. Not sure why it didnt work. But after redoing it and following your code (excluding graphics) it seems to work perfectly thank you